# Adding Windows Workflow to Custom Build Process (TFS 2010)

Tags: workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

I have a minor problem regarding my Custom Build Process Workflow in Team Foundation Server 2010.

At the moment, I have 2 custom workflows, one for Server Builds (.WSP Sharepoint packages) and one for client builds (.MSI Packages). These workflows have some separate steps but also a few steps which should apply for both.

For reasons of simplicity, I want "customize" as much as possible, directly in XAML Workflows, instead of creating Custom Activities.

One of these Custom Workflows, is a workflow which Signs .MSI and .WSP packages, which is relevant for both my Server- and my Client Build Process. The problem is that, unlike my Custom Code Activities, I can't add the "Activities" the Workflows creates to my Custom Build Process and neither do I want to copy all the whole Workflow Sequence into my Custom Workflow (this would neither be best practice, as I would have to make changes to places evert time I modified it).

I think has something to do with the fact that Custom Code Activities are sealed and the fact that you have to write "[BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]" before the class definition, which really isn't possible when creating a simple workflow :-)

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Best Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

> For reasons of simplicity, I want "customize" as much as possible, directly in XAML Workflows, instead of creating Custom Activities.

Unless your goal is learning how to edit build process templates,
my approach would be to use the default build template (so you don't need to maintain it). I would then extend the current solutions with a Sharepoint project's to create wsp's and wix project's for the msi's.